# Laravel Login page does nothing at all

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

fast and (hopefully) simple question. I am starting out with a project. I'm using de standard authorisation that comes with laravel. Registering a user works fine and it is logged in afterwards. I can also logout with no problem. The login screen seems fine. But when I enter my login credentials and click on 'login' nothing happens. no redirects or errors at all. It doesnt matter if I enter right, wrong or nothing at all in the login fields.

Login controller (Should be default):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/profile';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
}
```

Login view (should also be default):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="w-full max-w-xs mx-auto px-4">
        <h1 class="mb-4 text-center">Inloggen</h1>

        <form class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="mb-4">
                <label class="block text-grey-darker text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="username">
                    E-mailadres
                </label>
                <input id="email" type="email" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-grey-darker {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'border-red-dark' : 'border-grey-light' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                {!! $errors->first('email', '<p class="text-red text-xs italic">:message</p>') !!}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label class="block text-grey-darker text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="password">
                    Wachtwoord
                </label>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-grey-darker {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'border-red-dark' : 'border-grey-light' }}" name="password" required>
                {!! $errors->first('password', '<p class="text-red text-xs italic">:message</p>') !!}
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                <button class="bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-white py-2 px-4 rounded" type="button">
                    Inloggen
                </button>
                <a class="inline-block align-baseline text-xs text-grey hover:text-grey-dark" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                    Wachtwoord vergeten?
                </a>
            </div>
        </form>
        <p class="text-center text-grey text-xs">
            ©{{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. Alle rechten voorbehouden.
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Try displaying validation errors may be 'auth()->attempt()' is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your **Inloggen** button is the part that is wrong. Should be something like:

```html
<button class="bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-white py-2 px-4 rounded" type="submit">
  Inloggen
</button>
```

It needs to be type="**submit**" to submit form data.

Comment: yes! thank you. that was it. Still don't understand how that happened though. I'm sure I didn't changed that myself

Comment: Np problem. You can also replace "{{ csrf_field() }}" with "@csrf", They have added a blade template a while ago, I think it looks cleaner :)